# Does the JDBC Kafka Sink connector support Oracle partitioning when inserting / updating data in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am asking because I will have a sink that will be in "upsert" mode and the target Oracle table which is partitioned. I wonder if the update performance will be good due to millions of records in the target table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you be more specific? Your title asks about funcitonality, but your question asks about performance.

Comment: I am asking more about functionality of Kafka Connect/Sink connector in case of support of Oracle partitioning when data is fetched/inserted.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you've set your table's partition key on the column that you're using for the incremental predicate (ID / timestamp) I don't see why Oracle won't be able to take advantage of partition pruning to improve the fetch performance—but this is on the Oracle and data model side, not something that's implemented by the connector.

The connector does not support anything like partition-exchange loading etc.